# (PROLOG) Applying no repetition in "flatten" function

Tags: prolog

I have this function that flatten a list:

```
flatten([], []) :- !.
flatten([L|Ls], FlatL) :-
    !,
    flatten(L, NewL),
    flatten(Ls, NewLs),
    append(NewL, NewLs, FlatL),
flatten(L, [L]).
```

and "no duplicates" :

```
my_compress([], []):- !.

my_compress([X|Xs], Ys):-
          my_member(X, Xs),
          !,
          my_compress(Xs, Ys).

my_compress([X|Xs], [X|Ys]):-
          my_compress(Xs, Ys).
```

I have no idea how I can make a function with these two functions. I want to flatten a list without repetitions but in 1 function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could apply `my_compress/2` predicate to the flattened list recursively like:

```
flatten([], []) :- !.
flatten([L|Ls], FlatL) :-
    !,
    flatten(L, NewL),
    flatten(Ls, NewLs),
    append(NewL, NewLs, FL),
    my_compress(FL,FlatL).
flatten(L, [L]).
```

Example:

```
 ?- flatten([1,1,1,[[2],2],2,[3],3],L).
L = [1, 2, 3].
```